# ASP.net MVC - radio button validation is not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a radio button that is displaying a boolean field. When I submit the form data without checking the Radio button, it does not save as the field is required but it does not show a validation message. All the textboxes show the validation message, only the Radio button does not show validation message.

I have added:

- `[Required]` to the field in the view model
- `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.isCurrent)` in the view

However, it still does not show the error message.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

VIEWMODEL

```
    [Required]
    public bool? isCurrent { get; set; }
```

VIEW

```
<label type='checkbox'>
    Is this bus still a part of your fleet?
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isCurrent, true, new {id = "Yes"}) @Html.Label("Yes", "Yes")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isCurrent, false, new {id = "No"}) @Html.Label("No", "No")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.isCurrent)
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Do you have enabled client side validations and unobtrusive Javascript?

Comment: Also it good to check if razor pages are referencing validation js files.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out guys. I needed to wrap the Radio Buttons into a RadioButtonList.

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isCurrent, true, new {id = "Yes"}) @Html.Label("Yes", "Yes") @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isCurrent, false, new {id = "No"}) @Html.Label("No", "No") @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.isCurrent)

Comment: I just offered you the same answer above, which was successfully builded and tested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`. Also make sure you included jquery validation bundle or script at the bottom of the view. For instance:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<label type='checkbox'>
    Is this bus still a part of your fleet?
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isCurrent, true, new { id = "Yes" }) @Html.Label("Yes", "Yes")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isCurrent, false, new { id = "No" }) @Html.Label("No", "No")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.isCurrent)
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.isCurrent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</label>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
}


@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Hope this helped :)